# How do I delete a tuple in a list based on a value in the tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples. I want to remove all items in the list where the 2nd and 3rd items in the tuple are `bananas` and `1`. A for loop doesn't work since it's removing items from the list as it iterates through it. Not sure how else to go about this?

`my_table = [('apples', 'bananas', 1), ('pears', 'bananas', 1), ('grapes', 'apple', 2), ('apples,' 'pears', 2), ('apples', 'bananas', 2), ('grapes', 'bananas', 2)]`

```
>>> printTable(my_table)
('apples', 'bananas', 1)
('pears', 'bananas', 1)
('grapes', 'apple', 2)
('apples,pears', 2)
('apples', 'bananas', 2)
('grapes', 'bananas', 2)

>>> for item, row in enumerate(my_table):
    if row[1] == 'bananas' and row[2] == 1:
        print item, row

0 ('pears', 'bananas', 1)
5 ('apples', 'bananas', 1)
6 ('grapes', 'bananas', 1)

>>> for item, row in enumerate(my_table):
    if row[1] == 'bananas' and row[2] == 1:
        my_table.remove(row)

>>> printTable(my_table)
('pears', 'bananas', 1)
('grapes', 'apple', 2)
('apples,pears', 2)
('apples', 'bananas', 2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
my_table = [elem for elem in my_table if elem[1:] != ('bananas', 1)]
```

This looks at deletion as a filtering job; keep everything that should not be deleted by creating a new list instead.

Comment: It should be noted that this creates a *new* list, which is the correct and pythonic way of doing this.  The original list is not mutated.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
filterted_table=filter(lambda t: t[1:]!=('bananas', 1),my_table)
```